# Shower hot water not getting hot enough

Tags: plumbing, shower, hot-water, plumbing-fixture

I left my house unattended for a number of months.  Before leaving, I turned off the water to the house and drained the lines.  This was during the winter.  Anyway, now that I am home, I notice my downstairs (basement) shower does not get hot enough.  It gets warm but at its most hot, it is not as hot as it use to be.  The rest of the house is fine.  The other shower, sinks, etc. all heat up. I took photos of the parts as well as the pipes.  Can anyone give any suggestions on how to fix this?  I am not sure if this unit has a scald preventor on it.  I tried adjusting the inner white collar but that does not seem to help.  Or do I need to adjust the screws in the photo of the valve?  Any suggestions would be great.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you did nothing in the way of adjusting the hot cold mix I would suspect a partial blockage of the hot water side of the valve

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kris. Is this something that is easy to repair or needs to be done by a plumber?  Is the valve in the photo?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg5CdQgzscI. This may help not sure what brand your faucet is

Comment: It appears your faucet has a lot in common with the one in the link above. I would follow the instructions until the cartridge is out then open the hot water a bit to  clear the line of possible debris.   Carefully re insert cartridge in same position it came out

Comment: Thanks. I found a video on how to do it. Once the valve was exposed I removed all three cotter pins (after making sure the water was turned off). I then used a pair of pliers to pull out the central valve. You were right. There appeared to be wood fiber in the valve and in the pipe. After cleaning it out and putting everything back together, the hot water came back full force. Thank for the help. If you post a response I’ll mark it as correct.

Comment: And this was the video that helped: https://youtu.be/qnLMwkbU1V0. The only difference is that my valve has the shut off valves in the mixer (the two screws on each side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing low volume from  hot water in this valve and have not changed any of the mixing settings from when it worked properly I would suspect a partial blockage in the hot water supply line.

Carefully remove the cartridge from the valve body and look for debris. While cartridge is removed turn the water supply on a bit to flush out possible debris. Reassemble and test for normal operation. Good news your valve body has shut off screws for hot and cold water on it!

A valve repair video that shows a very similar type valve is found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg5CdQgzscI)